Can't access GRUB rescue menu with any hotkey (tried SHIFT, ESC, F8, SPACE). Where is this hotkey defined?
The basic question is where is this key defined in the system? But if you need the full background story:
My system doesn't boot (fails to mount) and won't allow me to access the root user from emergency mode ("the root account is locked").
I found that I should be able unlock the root user by accessing the GRUB menu. But no hotkey works on boot.
I can mount this system as an external drive on a live USB, and access its files that way. I can see it only has grub.cfg and there's no etc/default/grub file.
Is there any file where this hotkey for the grub menu is defined? All I could find online is a bunch of guesses that didn't work for me.
specs:
Dell laptop. OS is on external drive.
It has Debian 12 installed as part of the Umbrel server platform (which uses Mender as a wrapper).


UEFI uses escape key and BIOS uses shift key. You press escape just after UEFI/BIOS screen and before grub menu would normally appear. Timing is critical so often have to try several times. If UEFI fast boot setting is on in UEFI settings, you may not have time to press any key. Fast startup assumes no system change, so UEFI does not write hardware configuration to drive & immediately boots. You can often "cold" boot rather than "warm" reboot to get system to do a full rewrite of configuration and give just enough time to press escape.

I tried those keys but they didn't work. I ended up solving the error in a different way, but I'm keeping the question open because there has to be some place this key is defined, I'd still like to know what it is or verify that it's undefined.
